# Proof that a subset of a finite set is finite

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Can someone please tell me if this proof is rigorous? I have a hunch it's circular, and I am suspicious at how short it is. However, I'm also having trouble convincing myself that it's incorrect.

Suppose $B$ is a finite set and let $A \subseteq B$.
There exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\{1, 2, \dotsc, k\} \sim B$.
Set $k' = |B \setminus A|.$
Then $A$ is isomorphic to $\{1, 2, \dotsc, k - k'\}$, so it is finite.
Finite sets are countable, so $A$ is countable.

Thank you!

Comment: The obvious question this begs is "How do you know B\A is finite?"

Comment: Try using the definition that a set is infinite if it is in one-to-one correspondence with a subset of itself.

Comment: This is so obvious, so to prove it you need to use a rigorous definition of 'finite set'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not exactly circular, but when you use a symbol like $|B\setminus A|$, you are implicitly assuming that $B\setminus A$ is finite, which is premature.  Also, you can't just jump to saying that $A$ is isomorphic to a finite set -- you have to actually establish a bijection for that to happen.

The challenge of cleaning up this proof depends on how many tools you have at this point and how many tools you're being asked to build as homework.  There is clearly a bijection from $B$ to $1..n$ which you are allowed to choose.  You can manipulate that mapping to demonstrate an injection from $A$ to $1..n$.  Depending on your definitions, that may be enough to directly state that $A$ is finite (if, for instance, your definition is cardinality is the minimum $k$ such that there is an injection from $A$ to $1..k$).

On the other hand, if you need to find a bijection to prove finiteness, then you get to look forward to writing a lemma (hint: by induction on the maximum member of the set) that there exists a surjection from every finite subset of $\mathbb N$ to some set of the form $1..n$.

Comment: Thank you! I have to show a bijection. However, I don't see why your idea for showing an injection wouldn't also work. In particular, let $f : \{1, \dotsc, n\} \rightarrow B$ be a bijection. Then the restriction of $f$ to $A$ is also a bijection since $A \subseteq B$, right? Or is re-indexing $\{1, \dotsc, k\}$ non-trivial?

Comment: @VictorGinsburg You are right that that restriction is easy to describe, but it is only an injection to $B$ (and not a surjection if we took out elements).  Re-indexing is not particularly hard, and it should be obvious how to do it easily if you sit down with a piece of paper and make a few small examples, but it is not trivial so it does deserve that paragraph of a proof.